# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when switching from good database to old database

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I did a fresh install of WordPress 5.0 with a new database, and I can logon and view the dummy site.
Then I changed wp_config.php to connect to my original database (same release number).
When I do that, and browse to the site home page, I get the "redirected you too many times" (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

Comment: Likely your siteurl and/or home url in the options table are incorrect

Comment: I did check them, seemed correct to me.